# Test SetUp Vs TearDown

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation

We've seen test **setUp** and **tearDown** are being used regardless of platform and tools. But why do they matter in your tests? Why and how test setUp and tearDown play crucial role in your test execution?

In my opinion, test setUp is the initial state for all the tests. But you can reset the initial state before each test is run or executed. Whereas, tearDown is cleanup process and it will run after test is executed. In other word test tearDown is run on last-in first-out basis.
The simple example of test setUp cloud be **Open Browser** and tearDown could be **Close Browser**.

This is an open question you can have your thought.

Comment: Are you asking why we need initial setup vs each individual test set-up?  Your question is too general.

Comment: Yeah its a general question with my answer (understanding). If you have different thoughts then please answer those questions.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of them is crucial in respect to functionality, since they could be substituted in other ways, such as calling a function with the startup statements at the start of all test functions or calling another one after running the tests.

However, for the sake of organization and to avoid repetition, they are very helpful.

For example, I have a unit test for a database of mine, where I need to test whether my sign-up and login functions work. Since the sign-up function adds a user to the database, I need to restore it before the other tests, so that they are not compromised, and the setUp functions are very helpful for that.